# Problem with Ubuntu login with GNU GRUB

Tags: login, gnu

Usually, when I login, the Ubuntu login screen appears for selecting account and entering the password, but now suddenly a GNU GRUB panel appears for options like the ones shown in this image:

[image: GRUB image]

When I select the 1st option, it says unable to send h2c command. I googled it and I found a solution, which is to enter recovery mode in advanced options, but it was asking for login and password:

[image: login screen]

I tried with my usual credentials for Ubuntu and it says they are wrong. I don't know why this happens.

Before this event I downloaded NVIDIA drivers (.run file), but the installation stopped in the middle (stuck). During installation, it asked to set some kind of password and I set it same as my login password. It did not ask about username.After stopping installation as it was stuck i shutdown. Next time when i login this screen appeared.
I tried with different usernames like: "root", "user", "admin", "ubuntu", "boss", but none of them worked.

Please suggest me an easy way to get out of this. I am OK to uninstall Ubuntu, but I don't want any of the actions affect my Windows OS (dual boot on same laptop but different drives). And is there any way to remove this GNU GRUB screen? I don't want to see this again.

Comment: This looks like Debian, not Ubuntu. Please clarify.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04  sure and every time i shutdown i see Ubuntu logo.

Comment: From the GRUB menu, choose Advanced Options, Recovery Mode, Root Access. If it asks for a password, just try the ENTER key. Then try to reinstall Nvidia drivers. `sudo dpkg -i nvidia.deb` or `sudo apt-get install nvidia.deb` or `/path_to/nvidia.run`. Sub correct .deb file name. Drop `sudo` if it gives you trouble.

Comment: Thanks but i don't need Nvidia drivers( i just wanted to download so that in future it may help) and even i don't remember exact name i tried different names but it says package not found.

Comment: Installing Nvidia drivers without having a Nvidia card, is a bad idea, as you can see. Try to find the name with `dpkg -l *nvidia*`. Also see https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-uninstall-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

Comment: actually i have graphics card and i use it to play games on windows but on Ubuntu i don't need( because my graphics card GTX 1650 don't support CUDA for machine learning so no point to download but i hope it would help in stuff other than machine learning) and i tried to uninstall as you said but i still see same pannel asking for login and password.  and main thing is i want to login back to Ubuntu please help me

Comment: I think i didn't explain clearly i do all stuff in Windows but my senior suggest to use Ubuntu so i installed Ubuntu 2-3 month back but i didn't open it after installation. Few days back i opened it and install python ide packages etc.. then next day(login without any problem) i installed Nvidia driver but it stuck in middle so i stop it and shutdown laptop next time when i open this GNU screen appeared.

Comment: Either use my previous instructions to try and reinstall the Nvidia drivers and see if it completes this time, or follow the link to uninstall them. Either way, you need a clean install or uninstall.

Comment: Thanks for helping i tried but i didn't worked i am not familiar with Ubuntu or any Linux. I don't have time so i am reinstalling it. Sorry for wasting your time and thanks for helping